# Tensorflow Object Detection With Custom Model

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I follow this tut on this page: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

this tut use pre trained model graph 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'. Now I want to build my custom model, for my dataset

Is there a straightforward example to do this? I dont want to use Google Cloud Services at all for training, all action must be done on my local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!  You can definitely train locally using the command lines here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md

I would recommend that you use a GPU if you train locally.  Someone also wrote up a nice guide about how to train on a custom dataset here: https://medium.com/towards-data-science/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9 
In this case he used Cloud, but many of the tips will still be relevant even if training locally.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed [this guide](https://pythonprogramming.net/custom-objects-tracking-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/?completed=/video-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/), is awesome and practically easy, he shows how to train a Mac and cheese detector, hope it helps!
[image]